# How to view the contents of parsed R functions?

Tags: r, functional-programming

R is [a functional programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), and one of it's primary benefits is it's ability to create open and transparent functions.

As John Chambers says [in his excellent book "Software for Data Analysis: Programming with R"](http://books.google.com/books?id=UXneuOIvhEAC&printsec=frontcover):

> Computations are organized around functions, which can encapsulate specific, meaningful computational results, with implementations that can be examined for correctness.

Notions such as "reproducible research" and "trustworthy software" are at the heart of R development.  In general, it is easy to examine a function just by typing its name without parenthesis.  For instance:

```
> which
function (x, arr.ind = FALSE) 
{
    if (!is.logical(x)) 
        stop("argument to 'which' is not logical")
    wh <- seq_along(x)[x & !is.na(x)]
    dl <- dim(x)
...
```

My question is: how do you example the contents of functions such as `for()` or `if()` without downloading the R source code?

*Edit:* Incidentally, I understand that this won't help viewing compiled code (such as C, C++, or Java) that may be called from R.  I'm really wondering if there is an R function which output's R functions.

Comment: But but but...`for` and `if` are part of R's syntax, so you can't just inspect them; they're built-in.

Comment: (i.e., they're not functions per se, despite the visual similarity.)

Comment: I see!  They aren't functions.  That explains it.  They're more like the function "function" or other symbols such as <- or [; they're just part of the syntax.  If you put that in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: But you can't accept a correct answer to the wrong question :-)  You still want the sources to see the parser where you would have found this out too.

Comment: :-)  I am fully on-board with your comment about the Chambers book. "Software for Data Analysis" is strongly recommended reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the saying goes:  *Use the source, Luke!*

R functions may be visible at the prompt, but are still parsed meaning that comments are stripped, code indentation is changed etc.   So I would always go to the source.

Answer (score 2):

I also like going to the source for the same reasons mentioned by Dirk, but for quick and dirty work I also rely on subsets of:

`getAnywhere(), getFromNameSpace(), THEPACKAGE:::thefn, getGeneric()`

to see functions which are not exported by the namespace of their package.